# How to use Cases for nested list?

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering, conditional

For example,  we have a `list ={1,2,3,4,5,6}`,  we can use `Cases[list,x_/; 3<x<10]` to pick up `{4,5,6}`.

What if we are dealing with a nested list for example : `list2={{0.1,0.2},{0.1,0.2},{0.2,0.3},{0.3,0.4}}`;

Shall I use something like `Cases[list2,{x_,y_}/;0<x+y<0.5]` to pick up `{0.1,0.2}`in this case?

Comment: yes - but in both of your examples [`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) seems more natural than `Cases`

Comment: I tried to build a complex nested list using this method, but get empty result that's why I ask this

Comment: First you have to make sure that your pattern matches the elements that you are trying to get.  If it does, then you need to make sure that you are looking at the right level of your list.  By default, `Cases` will match only at the top level: `Cases[{{1},{2},{3}}, _Integer]` will return `{}` because the elements at the top level would match `{_Integer}`.  `Cases[{{1}, {2}, {3}}, _Integer, 2]`, however, returns `{1,2,3}`.  Look at the documentation for `Cases`, and look at the third argument in particular.

Comment: Thank you very much sir!

Answer (score 4):

As @JasonB. mentions in the comments [`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) is an alternative that some say *reads* better.

```
Select[0 < Total@# < .5 &]@list2
```

> ```
> {{0.1,0.2},{0.1,0.2}}
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You have answered your own question where you posted the question. Alternatively,

```
Cases[list2, x_ /; Plus @@ x < 0.5]
```

Comment: `Total @` might be more natural than `Plus @@`

Answer (score 1):

Yes looks correct, or you can put conditions on each one of the variables separated like that

```
Cases[list2, {x_, y_} /; x < 0.2 && y < 0.3]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a nested list with elements of varying lengths:

```
list = {{0.1, 0.2, 0.0}, {{0.1, 0.2}}, {0.2, 0.3}, {0.3, 0.4}};

Cases[list, p : {__?NumericQ} /; Total@p < 0.5, -1]
```

> {{0.1, 0.2, 0.}, {0.1, 0.2}}

Comment: Thanks for the supplement!